# I hosted my ASP.NET webservice in IIS with Entity Framework, but it is not accessible from outside

Tags: asp.net, iis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6moF.png)I have worked on a web service with Entity Framework. When I host the web service through IIS, but I am not able to access it. On localhost, it is working fine.

I have tried giving access from SQL Server Management Studio. Tried with Windows authentication as well as SQL Server authentication. Don't know what's wrong. Plus tried doing changes in `web.config` file.

Here is my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Chromoscan2Entities"  
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/CytoModel.csdl|res://*/CytoModel.ssdl|res://*/CytoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN10D-02198;initial catalog=Chromoscan2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? By 'outside' do you mean the internet? Are you talking about accessing your web application through a browser or are you talking about your web application being unable to access the database?

Comment: when i am giving hostname as localhost. i am able to browse.but if i give some othername for ex:cyto then i am getting error as "can't reach this page". By outside means from ohter device.yes i am talking about accessing my webservice through browser from other device when i host it from my device on iis.

Comment: If we are talking about browsing then SQL Server is irrelevant at this stage. If you want to browse a host called `cyto` from the internet then you need to buy that name and register it with an internet DNS company. Have you done that? Have you opened port 80 (or whatever port you are running on) in your router to your computer? I am making a lot of assumptions here. You need to provide more info.

Comment: can't i host it from my device only.and i keep this service running on my device and if somebody wants to access it with outside.they can access with my device ip:url..can this approach be used? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes you can use an IP address but you need to use the IP address of the router that is facing the internet, and you have to tell the router that any incoming requests on the web port (usually port 80) need to be directed to your device. You also need to ensure your ISP doesn't block that kind of activity. How is your device connecting to the internet?

Comment: through wifi modem.how can i configure the wifi modem to redirect ?do i have to make changes in the bindings in iis?

Comment: No you don't do anything in IIS. First go here https://www.whatismyip.com/ and find out what your internet facing (public) IP address is. That's the IP you need to type into your browser. Then you need to connect to the wifi modem configuration. I can't help you much with that. You could try typing 192.168.1.1 into your browser to see if it connects to the config page.

Comment: There are MANY guides on the internet to help you do what you're trying to do. Here's one: https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostmyown.html BTW that public facing IP is going to change every time you turn your WiFi modem off / on (or maybe even more frequently).

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of the tags you've attached. It needs to be migrated to a network site. Your actual issue is a very basic networking one that has been covered many times.

Comment: At IIS level, all you can do is to set valid site bindings for this web site, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Beyond that, all the remaining are networking related, like setting up DNS, firewall, and routing, which are not programming topics any more.

Comment: if i am trying to connect from my machine...means in browser in incognito mode if i am trying to access webservice using IP it is not connecting.I am attaching the screenshot for error. hostname i kept is localhost.

Comment: This is now a completely different question again. So all along you couldn’t access your web service from localhost???

Comment: yes@Nick.McDermaid